# Integrals and exponential functions as basis of functions

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I have a simple question. If two $2\pi$- periodic functions $f(x)$ and $u(x)$  satisfy  $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x) e^{u(x)}\ dx=0$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{2 u(x)}\ dx=0$. Does this imply $f(x)=0$ on $[0,2\pi]$? I have tried with the Wirtinger's inequality.

Comment: $u(x)$ a constant and $f(x)$ nonzero with zero average seems to contradict the statement

Comment: Yes, but u(x) is not constant. Or at least, it would be interesting to me that I could conclude that u(x) is constant.

Comment: The functions f=f(x) and u=u(x) are sufficiently smooth.

Comment: Denoting $g:=\exp u$, the conditions $<f,g>=0=<f,g^2>$ only seem to me to determine a subspace of co-dimension $\leq 2$ in $L^2(0,2\pi)$, far from characterizing only the zero function. For example $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=\cos(x)$ seem to contradict the conclusion.

Comment: EDIT: in my last comment, last statement is $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $u(x)=\cos (x)$ seem to contradict the conclusion.

Comment: Right! it is true that $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle f,g^2\rangle=0$ is a weak condition in the space  $L^2[0,2\pi]$. However, in your example, $\cos(x)\not= e^{u(x)}$.

Comment: Perfect! it is a good example.